# How do I grab info from a website that I need to log into

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

so I'm trying to grab my grades from canvas.net and in order to see my grades on google sheets. but I have to sign in to see them.

so I'm using this code to grab the data but I know it can't see my grades because I'm not signed in so how do I sign into the website using google sheets.

```
importxml("https://learn.canvas.net/grades", "//td")
```

I haven't tried anything because I have no idea where to start

Comment: You should try and break your problem into smaller problems.
First, what kind of login does the website have in place? Is it a standard web form, is it a reactive js form, is it http basic auth?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access site behind the login using importxml or other google sheets tools.

**Why?**
When you write import formula, it's not you who connects to canvas.net or other site, it's Google Sheets server. That's why it can't reach your data. You are authorised, google server is not.

Comment: so there's no way to open like a popup to the website that will allow me to login